# How should I markup price columns and setup fee according to schema.org

Tags: markup, microdata, schema.org

In the promotional products industry, an item will be offered at a certain price with a minimum quantity. Then, there will be another quantity level after which the price per piece goes down. There might be 5 or 6 of these levels.

In addition to the price per item, there is almost always a setup fee because they are being custom printed.

How do I mark this up using schema.org vocabulary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [schema.org/Offer](http://schema.org/Offer) class and its property [eligibleQuantity](http://schema.org/eligibleQuantity)

Description of *eligibleQuantity* says

> The interval and unit of measurement of ordering quantities for which the offer or price specification is valid. This allows e.g. specifying that a certain freight charge is valid only for a certain quantity.

Seems it's what you need. 
Markup may look like this

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">$55.00</span>
    <div itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
        <span itemprop="minValue">1</span>
        <span itemprop="maxValue">5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment I marked up each price as a separate offer. The trick for me now is to relate each qty column with its price without changing the appearance of the site. I might have to resort to `<meta>` for that.